# How to invoke "map a network drive"?

Tags: networking, vbscript

I'm using a script which is calling (via sh.run) "net use". On the first computer, net is allowed to be run by my user. On the second one, net is an unauthorized command (restricted by a domain policy).

Could I simply copy/rename/move the net.exe in order to execute it, even if it is not allowed?
If not, is there a way to invoke the "GUI style" connector?

Comment: Copying the file net.exe will certainly not work, you may not even have write access to the folder in which it is located. If you are using VBA then why do you need the GUI, the user could do that manually without VBA else Sean's answer below is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of how to connect `H:` to `\\myserver\users`

```
Dim objNetwork
Set objNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strLocalDrive = "H:"
strRemoteShare = "\\myserver\users"
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strLocalDrive, strRemoteShare, False
```